# React-style controlled components (bound input) with Angular

Tags: angular

I can't figure out how to implement React-style controlled components in Angular. The behavior I'm trying to implement is related to mat-select, but this seems to work the same way with regular selects as well. So here's what I'd like to achieve:

- the select receives it's value via an input
- when the select changes, the parent component will receive the change and handle it. It's the parent's business how it handles the change.
- if the parent does not change the value of the input, I would like the select to still display the initial value, despite the user's attempted change

This is [trivial to implement in React](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-controlled-material-select), as it is the default behavior for any sort of input. I tried to achieve a similar behavior in Angular using `[ngModel]` along with `(ngModelChange)`, but [it seems I'm doing it wrong](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bound-mat-select).

It might seem like it's a weird behavior to ask for, but that's not the case: the selection change might trigger an async action that might succeed or fail, so it would make sense that in case of failure the value would not change. [Here's an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-controlled-material-select-realworld): the update will fail half the time; when it does, the value stays the same, otherwise it changes to the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I could come up with is more like a hack, but it seems to work.

For Angular, you need to make the mat-select *believe* that there was an update on the value.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';

const fruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  readonly fruits = fruits;
  selectedFruit = '';
  allowChanges = true;

  selectFruit(newValue: string) {
    if (this.allowChanges) {
      this.selectedFruit = newValue;
    }
    // What follows is a hack so that the mat-select thinks there was a change
    // even if there wasn't.
    // This make sure the mat-select always shows the value specified by
    // `this.selectedFruit`.
    const oldValue = this.selectedFruit;
    const anInvalidValue = '.';
    this.selectedFruit = anInvalidValue;
    setTimeout(() => {
      // This is here to prevent a race condition. If they are different, it
      // means `this.selectedFruit` was changed in the meantime.
      if (this.selectedFruit === anInvalidValue) {
        this.selectedFruit = oldValue;
      }
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite Fruit</mat-label>
    <mat-select
      [ngModel]="selectedFruit" (ngModelChange)="selectFruit($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [value]="fruit">
        {{fruit}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</section>
<section>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="allowChanges">Allow changes</mat-checkbox>
</section>
<section>
  Allow Changes value: {{allowChanges}}
  <br>
  Favorit Fruit value: {{selectedFruit}}
</section>
```

See it in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bound-mat-select-men5d2).